# What does this property of marginal CDFs mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

I am studying Join probability distributions and random variables. I've come across joint distribution functions (or cumulative distribution functions), and the following property:

$F_X(x) = F_{XY}(x, \infty)$

I just want to make sure my understanding is correct. Does this mean to say that the marginal probability is equal to the joint probability where Y $P(Y=y)=1?$ What if the random variables X,Y are dependent?

Or does it mean to say that $F_X(X)$ is the same regardless of what Y is?

Can someone please explain this property to me?

Comment: It simply means $F_{X,Y}(x,\infty)=\lim_{y\to \infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)= P(X\le x,Y\in \mathbb R)=P(X\le x)=F_X(x)$, which is a way to find marginal distribution function from joint distribution function.

Comment: For $P(X \leq x, Y \in \mathbb{R})$ = $P(X \leq x)$, is $(Y \in \mathbb{R})$ disappearing  because it equates to 1?

Comment: It might help if you write down $F_{X,Y}(x,\infty)$ explicitly assuming $(X,Y)$ is discrete/absolutely continuous.

Comment: Suppose $P(B) = 1$. Then $P(A\cup B) \geq P(B) = 1 \Rightarrow P(A \cup B) = 1$. By inclusion-exclusion, $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) \Rightarrow P(A\cap B) = P(A)$

Comment: @BGM thanks. So, this is what I meant in my previous comment. We can leave Y out because its a certainty (the probability is 1), which means $P(X \leq x, Y \in \mathbb{R} )$ or "the probability of X being x && Y belonging to R" really just depends on X = x, since $Y \in \mathbb{R}$ is a certainty. Thanks for spelling it out this way.